# XSSFSheet Apache POI - is it possible to lock everything but allowing update and insert rows?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I try to lock the whole sheet but some columns should be unlocked (I want to add values in some columns). I want to copy some row, add new row and paste values from copied row. Is it possible?

```
 public ByteArrayResource getQuestionnaireTemplate(List<QuestionnaireTemplateDto> questionnaireTemplateInitialData) throws IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = excelExportService.createExcelWorkBook();

        String frameworkName = questionnaireTemplateInitialData.stream().map(QuestionnaireTemplateDto::getFramework).findFirst().orElse("Framework Name");
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(frameworkName);
//        sheet.lockInsertColumns(true);
//        sheet.lockInsertRows(false);
        sheet.enableLocking();
//        sheet.lo
//        CellStyle unlockedCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
//        unlockedCellStyle.setLocked(false);

        CTSheetProtection sheetProtection = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetProtection();
        sheetProtection.setSelectLockedCells(false);
        sheetProtection.setSelectUnlockedCells(false);
        sheetProtection.setFormatCells(false);
        sheetProtection.setFormatColumns(false);
        sheetProtection.setFormatRows(false);
        sheetProtection.setInsertColumns(false);
        sheetProtection.setInsertRows(false);
        sheetProtection.setInsertHyperlinks(false);
        sheetProtection.setDeleteColumns(false);
        sheetProtection.setDeleteRows(false);
        sheetProtection.setSort(false);
        sheetProtection.setAutoFilter(false);
        sheetProtection.setPivotTables(false);
        sheetProtection.setObjects(false);
        sheetProtection.setScenarios(false);
```

Amd then for some row I can set some cell as editable (it works):

```
  private void addFieldRow(XSSFSheet sheet, XSSFCellStyle fieldRowStyle, QuestionnaireTemplateDto questionnaireTemplateDto) {
        XSSFRow row = excelExportService.createRow(sheet,
                sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1,
                Arrays.asList(questionnaireTemplateDto.getFrameworkFieldId().toString(), questionnaireTemplateDto.getFramework(), questionnaireTemplateDto.getFieldName(), questionnaireTemplateDto.getYear().toString()),
                fieldRowStyle);

        CellStyle unlockedStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        unlockedStyle.setLocked(false);
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellStyle(unlockedStyle);
    }
```

My generated sheet works perfectly except for one small detail - I can't insert new row and copy some other row to it...

I think I tried all solutions from Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [XSSFSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html) methods instead of low level `CTSheetProtection` methods for specifying sheet protection. In current `apache poi 4.1.2` there are all possibilities also useable using `XSSFSheet.lock...`- methods.

But what you want is not completely possible. Sheet protection mainly protects **cells** from changing. So if you allow deleting rows and the row contains protected cells, then deleting the row contradicts the cell protection. The same is for copying a row into another. If that other row contains protected cells, then copying also contradicts the cell protection.

Following complete example creates a workbook having one sheet where all cells are protected except columns `A`, `C` and `E`. The sheet protection allows formatting rows, inserting rows and deleting rows. But deleting rows contradicts the cell protection of all cells in that row except those in columns `A`, `C` and `E`. So deleting rows is allowed but not possible.

So the resulting sheet allows only changing cells  in columns `A`, `C` and `E`, formatting rows (row height) and inserting rows.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateExcelXSSFProtectedSheet {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  CellStyle notLocked = workbook.createCellStyle();
  notLocked.setLocked(false);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, notLocked); // column A is not locked
  sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(2, notLocked); // column C is not locked
  sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(4, notLocked); // column E is not locked

  ((XSSFSheet)sheet).lockFormatRows(false); // formatting rows is allowed
  ((XSSFSheet)sheet).lockInsertRows(false); // inserting rows is allowed
  ((XSSFSheet)sheet).lockDeleteRows(false); // deleting rows is allowed but may contradict cell protection

  sheet.protectSheet("");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelXSSFProtectedSheet.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: OK, so I can add new rows but I can't copy existing rows into newly created rows... I can't even copy values from locked columns... But if it's impossible to do then OK:) Thank you for your answer:)