# NPOI Enable Filtering on Protected Sheet

Tags: c#, excel, filtering, spreadsheet, npoi

I have problem with generating excel with autofilter on, in protected sheet with NPOI.
I got an excel template that look like this:
[image: excel_01]

What we need to achieve is, enable filter in every header, and protect the sheet.
It would be like this:
[image: excel_02]

This can be achieved with, check Sort and AutoFilter in Review > Protect Sheet in Excel.
[image: excel_03]

I am trying to reproduce this using NPOI. But, the filter in header cannot be clicked, and the **Use AutoFilter** and **Sort** in Protect Sheet is not checked.

My code:

```
IWorkbook workbook = null;
ISheet worksheet = null;

using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(infoFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(FS);
    worksheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
}

//SET FILTER
worksheet.SetAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.ValueOf("A3:G3"));

//SET PROTECTED SHEET
XSSFSheet bullSheet = ((XSSFSheet)worksheet);
bullSheet.LockAutoFilter(false);
bullSheet.LockSort(false);
bullSheet.LockSelectLockedCells(false);

bullSheet.ProtectSheet("");

//EXPORT FILE
Stream excelStream = new MemoryStream();
workbook.Write(excelStream, true);

var fileStream = File.Create(infoFile.DirectoryName + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(infoFile.FullName) + "_test.xlsx");
excelStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
excelStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
fileStream.Close();
excelStream.Close();
```

I've tried several solution from another questions, but it didn't give the same result [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242130/xssfsheet-apache-poi-is-it-possible-to-lock-everything-but-allowing-update-and), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701322/apache-poi-how-to-protect-sheet-with-options), [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155205/enable-filtering-and-sorting-in-a-protected-sheet-using-apache-poi).

Please help to fix this. I believe something is wrong or less.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a same problem.
Thought I'm not sure that this is correct solution,
Calling All Unlock methods after Protect method, filter is enabled.
Could you try this?